# Widget ordering in Widget Gallery

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I have a WidgetBundle that contains multiple widgets in the following format:

```
@main
struct SampleBundle: WidgetBundle {
    @WidgetBundleBuilder
    var body: some Widget {
        Widget1()
        Widget2()
        Widget3()
    }
}
```

When I launch the Widget Gallery the widgets appear in the order defined above, but the carousel does not always default to the first widget / slide for the user to add. So there would be situations where the second widget (2nd slide) or 3rd is shown by default and the user needs to swipe back in order to get to the first slide.

Ideally, I'd like to always default to the first widget. Most of the apps that have widget bundles have this functionality, so I figured there must be something obvious that I'm missing.

A few notes:

- All widgets in the bundle only support small widget family
- All widgets in the bundle have dynamic intents
- All widgets in the bundle have placeholders defined

Any help is greatly appreciated!